# UITableView overlap cells (force)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, calayer

I want to accomplish a table view cell overlap since I want to accomplish this effect:

[image: stacking]

So basically cells would kind of stack one on another. I'm targeting iOS7+ (currently testing with iOS8).

I'm currently doing a `CAGradientLayer` which gets positioned in `layoutSubviews`. I'm positioning it with:

```
CGRect gradientLayerFrame = self.contentView.bounds;
gradientLayerFrame.origin.y = -6.0f;
gradientLayerFrame.size.height += 6.0f;
self.gradientLayer.frame = gradientLayerFrame;
```

And I also did the

```
self.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;
self.contentView.superview.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

in `init` so that nothing would clip. Now the cell clips the first time it gets rendered but when I scroll the table view down and then up again so that it displays the cells again they don't get clipped.

I already tried setting `backgroundColor` to clear in `willDisplayCell` with no luck. Also tried recursively traversing all of the cells subviews and set clipping to NO but the same thing all over again. Also tried hacking and forcefully setting `setNeedsDisplay` so that things would re-render but no luck.

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to set `clipsToBounds` of the cells in somewhere like `didlayoutsubviews`?

Comment: Isn't `viewDidLayoutSubviews` called on the `UIViewController`? I don't really see how that can be of any use here. Then I would have to traverse visible cells of the table view and set clipping. That seems a bit hacky.

Comment: that is an optical illusion only, there is no overlapping here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be a TableView.

Try this library: [TGLStackedViewController](https://github.com/gleue/TGLStackedViewController)

Comment: Indeed. I was pseudo hacking it when trying to do it with a table view. This is the right approach. I didn't have enough time to implement my custom solution and didn't know this library. Things are working now, just needs a bit more tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue some time back.

The solution that worked for me is using a Collection view instead of a TableView. Create a custom class by extending it from UICollectionViewFlowLayout and use that in your Collection View instead.

```
class OverlappedCustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        // This allows us to make intersection and overlapping
        // A negative number implies overlapping whereas positive implies space between the adjacent edges of two cells.
        minimumLineSpacing = -100
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
        for currentLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in layoutAttributes! {

            // zIndex - Specifies the item’s position on the z-axis. 
            // Unlike a layer's zPosition, changing zIndex allows us to change not only layer position, 
            // but tapping/UI interaction logic too as it moves the whole item.
            currentLayoutAttributes.zIndex = currentLayoutAttributes.indexPath.row + 1
        }
    }

    return layoutAttributes
}
```

P.S. - As per Apple's developer document of [zIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayoutattributes/1617768-zindex)

> This property is used to determine the front-to-back ordering of items
>   during layout. Items with higher index values appear on top of items
>   with lower values. Items with the same value have an undetermined
>   order. The default value of this property is 0.

Hope it helps! :)